# File Directory listing returning null

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new at android programming and I can't seem to get this function to work. I've added the needed permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE with no luck. I've also tried using Files as well as strings (as you'll see in the commented code) with no luck. Anyone have any pointers? Thanks.

```
File directoryPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());

        if (directoryPath.exists() && directoryPath.isDirectory()) {
            //String FileName = "keyword";
        /*final*/ //Pattern p = Pattern.compile(FileName);

           String Filelist[] = directoryPath.list();
          //File[] flist = directoryPath.listFiles();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for permissions in runtime?

Comment: need to ask [Run time permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) in marshmellow and above devices

Comment: That was it! Thank you!